# App identification for iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I came across this website: https://www.apple.com/in/apple-pencil/  by Apple about the Apple Pencil. Apple has used the screenshot of an app as the header of the website. Can anyone help me figure out which graphics design app is featured in the screenshot? (The screenshot consists of an illustration by Malika Favre)[image]

Comment: Apple may have just mocked-up a screen for the demo photo. Visit [this site](https://www.creativebloq.com/digital-art/art-on-the-ipad-1232669) at CreativeBloq for some reviews of popular, and powerful-looking, graphic design apps.

Comment: @IconDaemon WOW! Got it the App is Graphic, found it in the blog you gave me a link for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Graphic for iPad.  It was Autodesk Graphic, but it appears Autodesk sold it back to founders they acquired 3 years ago.

http://www.graphic.com